# Android: long click on the child views of a ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

ExpandableListView has a setOnChildClickListener method, but lacks of **setOnChild**Long**ClickListener** method.

When I added `setOnLongClickListener()` on child view in `getChildView()`, whole sublist became completely unclickable (despite of `parentView.setOnChildClickListener()` present and working before).

How can I enable long clicks on child views?

Comment: See detail answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646098/android-can-i-use-setonlongclicklistener-and-setonclicklistener-for-same-butto/23646241#23646241

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I found an answer on Steve Oliver's blog here: http://steveoliverc.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/context-menus-for-expandable-lists/

You should use `onCreateContextMenu()` instead of looking for `setOnChildLongClickListener()`. Here is Steve's info:

*An expandable list supports context menus in pretty much the same way that a standard list does: add a listener for the context menu (when the user has long-pressed on a list item). Unlike a standard list view, however, you probably want to know whether the user has selected a group (expandable item) or a child (sub-item) list item.*

*Furthermore, you might not want to do anything if the user tries to bring up a context menu on a group item. There might be cases where you would want to do something to all of the children under a group, but in my Librarium application, I wanted to ignore group items and present the context menu only for children.*

*First, you need to know when the context menu is going to be created so that you can identify whether the user pressed on a group or a child. If they pressed on a group, then cancel the context menu. This also gives us a chance to get the text of the child item, so that we can put it into the header of the context menu.*

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)             
{
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

  ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info =
    (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

  int type =
    ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);

  int group =
    ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);

  int child =
    ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

  // Only create a context menu for child items
  if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) 
  {
    // Array created earlier when we built the expandable list
    String page =mListStringArray[group][child];

    menu.setHeaderTitle(page);
    menu.add(0, MENU_READ, 0, “Read page”);
    menu.add(0, MENU_EDIT, 0, “Edit page”);
    menu.add(0, MENU_FAVORITE, 0, “Add page to favorites”);
    menu.add(0, MENU_EXPORT, 0, “Export page to file”);
    menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE, 1, “Delete page”);
  }
}
```

Secondly, create the Context Menu:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) 
{
  ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = 
    (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuItem.getMenuInfo();

  int groupPos = 0, childPos = 0;

  int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
  if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) 
  {
    groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
    childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);
  }

  // Pull values from the array we built when we created the list
  String author = mListStringArray[groupPos][0];
  String page = mListStringArray[groupPos][childPos * 3 + 1];
  rowId = Integer.parseInt(mListStringArray[groupPos][childPos * 3 + 3]);

  switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
  {
    case MENU_READ:
      readNote(rowId);
      return true;

    case MENU_EDIT:
      editNote(rowId);
      return true;

    // etc..

    default:
      return super.onContextItemSelected(menuItem);
  }
}
```

*That’s it. Now users can long-press on an item in an expandable list, and get the context menu if it’s a child item.*

Comment: As a side note, don't forget the registerForContextMenu call in the onCreate method. If you (like me) forget that, then nothing will work.

Comment: As well, don't forget to override isChildSelectable to return true in your implementation of BaseExpandableListAdapter. Without this, the children view will not respond to long clicks.

Answer (score 90):

I managed to get long clicks working on an `ExpandableListView` child item, using the following:

```
getExpandableListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
            int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);

            // You now have everything that you would as if this was an OnChildClickListener() 
            // Add your logic here.

            // Return true as we are handling the event.
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

It took ages to figure out that the id argument in onItemLongClick was the `packedPosition` argument required by `getPackedPosition`* methods, certainly not clear from the documentation.

**Note:** For this solution to work you need to override the `getGroupId` and `getChildId()` methods in your adapter

```
   @Override
   public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
      return groupPosition;
   }

   @Override
   public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return childPosition;
   }
```

Comment: An elegant, working solution. Does not conflict with OnChildClickListener.

Comment: I have followed this solution and found problem. It throws outOfIndexException when I tried to get object from datasource of list adapter with these `childPosition` and `groupPosition`.
I found another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806100/identifying-the-group-that-has-been-clicked-in-an-expandablelistview

that explain why I can not use id for this situation. 
At last, I have solved my problem with the answer ( you can find in MY below/above answer).

Comment: This didn't work for me, the childPosition was always 0, so I used autobot_101's answer.

Comment: It's a thing of beauty :)

Comment: It is working for child item long click, but I need it for group and I tried this code for group onItemLongClick, it is worked when group is not expanded and not worked when group is expanded and I press long on group item.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659207/expandablelistview-getpackedpositiongroup-always-returns-0-in-onitemlongclick has a alternate working solution if your `packedPositionType` is always not `child`.

Answer (score 32):

I know this answer may be no need, but I have similar situation and non of these answer solve my problem.
So I post mine in case someone may need it.
Hope all you guys don't mind.

```
@Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View childView, int flatPos, long id) {
                     if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                            final ExpandableListAdapter adapter = ((ExpandableListView) parent).getExpandableListAdapter();
                            long packedPos = ((ExpandableListView) parent).getExpandableListPosition(flatPos);
                            int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPos);
                            int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPos);

                        // do whatever you want with groupPos and childPos here - I used these to get my object from list adapter.
                    return false;
                }
```

**Edit**
This solution for Listview was long time ago. I highly recommend to move to **RecyclerView** now.

Comment: +1. This is _the correct_ solution. You need flat(raw) position of view first, not just id of object at that position.

Comment: wow!!!! Agree! Could not get te childPosition from earlier examples. It was always the same i.e. ZERO - but now, when I implemented this code, it seems to work perfect!. I'll make a vote.

Comment: autobot_101: My vote goes to your answer. This answer should get maximum votes.

Comment: This is the correct answer, use an else on this if to get the group long click listener

Comment: Awesome.  I've been struggling with this one, so your answer makes my day.

Answer (score 13):

I was searching for this answer, but non here gave correct results.

Marked answer from [tomash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354595/836138) suggest completely different way. Answer from [Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8320128/836138) is partially correct, but using 'id' is incorrect.

Correct, working, answer is: convert `position` parameter to `packedPosition` and THEN! using this new `packedPosition` value to obtain group and child ID's. Check code below

```
    getExpandableListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            long packedPosition = getExpandableListView().getExpandableListPosition(position);
            if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(packedPosition) == 
                    ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                // get item ID's
                int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);
                int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition);

                // handle data 
                ...

                // return true as we are handling the event.
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**: I now see that [autobot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16436288/836138) has almost correct solution, except testing `getPackedPositionType` on `id` and not on `packetPosition`

Comment: what is exListView in your answer?

Comment: ah sorry, I've improved code above. `exListView` was `ExpandableListView` object. Same as the one, on which you set this listener

Comment: Thumbs up for this one. Using position is better than using id to get packedPosition.

Answer (score 1):

I handle ur problem. just set a tag ur item and use it ,like this:

```
adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter() {


        private String[] groups = { "Biceps", "Deltoids", "Hamstrings", "Lower Back","Quadriceps","Triceps","Wrist" };
        private String[][] children = {
                { "Konsantra Dumbell curl", "Hammer curl", "Barbell Biceps Curl", "Prone Curl" },
                { "Arnold Press", "Lateral Raise", "Dumbell Upright row", "Bar Military Press" },
                { "Dead Lift", "Hack Squat","Zercher Squat","Seated Leg Flexion" },
                { "Back Raise", "Superman" },
                { "Back Squat", "Bulgarian Split Squat","Dumbell Lunge" },
                { "Bench Dip", "French Press","Triceps Extension" },
                { "Dumbell Wrist Curl "," Reverse Writst Curl"}
        };
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             TextView textView = getGenericView();
                textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
                textView.setTag((Object)getGroup(groupPosition).toString()+"G");
                return textView;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return groups.length;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public long getCombinedGroupId(long groupId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public long getCombinedChildId(long groupId, long childId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             TextView textView = getGenericView();
                textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
                textView.setTag((Object)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString()+"C");
                return textView;
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return childPosition;
        }

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

            TextView textView = new TextView(expandXml.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // Center the text vertically
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            // Set the text starting position
            textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);

            return textView;
        }

    };
```

And then setOnItemLongClickListener for Expandable ListView.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s=null;

                int childPosition =ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(arg3);
                if(arg1.getTag()!=null){
                Object o= arg1.getTag();

                 s = o.toString();
                }
                Toast.makeText(expandXml.this ,s , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here we go.