# Identifying the group that has been clicked in an expandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to identify a view that has been clicked in an expandableListView. When I set an `OnItemLongClickListener` I get an argument that shows me the position of the clicked view inside the list. However, it also counts child views. I'd like it to count only groups, so when a group was clicked I can determine which one it was. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the long parameter is not the packed value, this is the ID generated by your adapter (`getCombinedChildId()`). Attempting to interpret an ID, even if you generate it in a certain way would be a bad idea. Id is an id.

I believe the right way is to use `ExpandableListView.getExpandableListPosition(flatPos)` method. Your "pos" argument passed to the listener is, in fact, flat list position. `getExpandableListPosition()` method returns the packed position which can be then decoded into separate group and child positions using the static methods of `ExpandableListView`.

I have hit this problem myself today so I am describing the solution I have found working for me.

Comment: Just to easier to someone in the future here's an example: `ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(expListView.getExpandableListPosition(position))`

Answer (score 2):

The `long id` parameter passed by the `onItemLongLongClick` method is a packed value.
You can retrieve group position with `ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id)`
Child position is obtained with  `ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id)`.
If Child == -1 then the long click was on the group item.

Below is an example listener class demonstrating unpacking of `id`.

```
private class expandableListLongClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
    public boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> p, View v, int pos, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setTitle("Long Click Info");
        String msg = "pos="+pos+" id="+id;
        msg += "\ngroup=" + ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
        msg += "\nchild=" + ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {   }
        } );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();           
        return true;
    }
}
```