# How to identify a groupView that has been clicked in an expandablelistview?

Tags: java, android

I just want to identify that which groupView has been clicked from an expandableListView. Cause I want to send the clicked groupView's text to another activity. I have also seen this link, but it didn't solve my problem. 
[Identifying the group that has been clicked in an expandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806100/identifying-the-group-that-has-been-clicked-in-an-expandablelistview)
I also tried by sending the groupPosition and it still didn't solve my problem.
Here is my code.

**CategoryList.java:**

```
package com.remindme.sayem.remindme;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class CategoryList extends AppCompatActivity {

private ExpandableListView categoryListView;
private CategoryListAdapter categoryListAdapter;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String> > listDataChild;
int group_size, child_size;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_list);
    categoryListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.categoryListView);

    prepareListData();

    categoryListAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    categoryListView.setAdapter(categoryListAdapter);
    categoryListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

            if(categoryListAdapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryList.this, ItemEditorActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("GROUP_POSITION", groupPosition);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

}

private  void prepareListData(){
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String> >();

    // Adding group data
    listDataHeader.add("Pharmacy");
    listDataHeader.add("Super Shop");
    listDataHeader.add("Stationery Shop");
    listDataHeader.add("Market");
    listDataHeader.add("Hotel");
    listDataHeader.add("Hardware shop");
    listDataHeader.add("Computer Accessories Shop");
    listDataHeader.add("Others");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> pharmacy = new ArrayList<String>();
    pharmacy.add("a");
    pharmacy.add("a");
    pharmacy.add("a");
    pharmacy.add("a");
    pharmacy.add("a");

    List<String> super_shop = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> stationery_shop = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> market = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> hotel = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> hardware_shop = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> computer_accessories_shop = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> others = new ArrayList<String>();

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), pharmacy);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), super_shop);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), stationery_shop);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), market);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), hotel);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), hardware_shop);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), computer_accessories_shop);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), others);
}

public class CategoryListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // Header titles
    private HashMap<String, List<String> > _listDataChild; // Child Items

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    public CategoryListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        group_size = this._listDataHeader.size();
        return group_size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        child_size = this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
        //CategoryList.this.group_size = groupPosition;
        return child_size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_item, null);
        }
        TextView categoryItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryItem);
        categoryItem.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_name, null);
        }

        TextView itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        itemName.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

**ItemEditorActivity.java:**

```
package com.remindme.sayem.remindme;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ItemEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText itemEditorEditText;
Button doneButton;
Button addDataButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_editor);
    itemEditorEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemEditorEditText);
    doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    addDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDataButton);
    addDataButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.addDataButton:
            String itemEditorString = itemEditorEditText.getText().toString();
            ItemListDatabase itemListDatabase = new ItemListDatabase(ItemEditorActivity.this);
            itemListDatabase.open();
            if (getIntent().getIntExtra("GROUP_POSITION", 0) == 0)
            {
                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoPharmacy(itemEditorString);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("GROUP_POSITION", 0) == 1){
                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoSuperShop(itemEditorString);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("GROUP_POSITION", 0) == 2){
                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoStationeryShop(itemEditorString);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("GROUP_POSITION", 0) == 3){
                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoMarket(itemEditorString);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("GROUP_POSITION", 0) == 4){
                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoHotel(itemEditorString);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("GROUP_POSITION", 0) == 5){
                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoHardwareShop(itemEditorString);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (getIntent().getIntExtra("GROUP_POSITION", 0) == 6){
                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoComputerAccessoriesShop(itemEditorString);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            itemListDatabase.close();
            break;

        case R.id.doneButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(ItemEditorActivity.this, CategoryList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**activity_category_list.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.remindme.sayem.remindme.CategoryList"
>

<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/categoryListView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:divider="#7AA410"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_item_editor.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.remindme.sayem.remindme.ItemEditorActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/itemEditorEditText" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Add Data"
        android:id="@+id/addDataButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:text="DONE"
        android:id="@+id/doneButton" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**category_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#7AA410"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/categoryItem" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_name.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/itemName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please insert xml code.

Comment: I inserted the xml files.

Comment: I solved it!!!! Please see my answer in the EDIT_CODE section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDIT_CODE**

I made this change of categoryListView.setOnGroupClickListener() method inside the **CategoryList.java**.

```
categoryListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

            if(categoryListAdapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryList.this, ItemEditorActivity.class);

                String text = categoryListAdapter.getGroupText(groupPosition);
                intent.putExtra("GROUP_POSITION", text);
                Toast.makeText(CategoryList.this, "Group Position: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also I added a new function getGroupText() in the CategoryListAdapter class inside the **CategoryList.java**.

```
public String getGroupText(int groupPosition){
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).toString();
    }
```

After that I edited the **ItemEditorActivity.java** like this.

```
package com.remindme.sayem.remindme;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ItemEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText itemEditorEditText;
Button doneButton;
Button addDataButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_editor);
    itemEditorEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemEditorEditText);
    doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    addDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDataButton);
    addDataButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.addDataButton:
            ItemListDatabase itemListDatabase = new ItemListDatabase(this);
            String itemEditorString = itemEditorEditText.getText().toString();
            ItemNameClass itemNameClass = new ItemNameClass(itemEditorString);
            String group_position = getIntent().getStringExtra("GROUP_POSITION");
            if (group_position.equals("Pharmacy"))
            {
                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoPharmacy(itemNameClass);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to " + group_position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (group_position.equals("Super Shop")) {

                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoSuperShop(itemNameClass);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to " + group_position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (group_position.equals("Stationery Shop")) {

                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoStationeryShop(itemNameClass);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to " + group_position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (group_position.equals("Market")) {

                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoMarket(itemNameClass);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to " + group_position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (group_position.equals("Hotel")) {

                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoHotel(itemNameClass);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to " + group_position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (group_position.equals("Hardware Shop")) {

                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoHardwareShop(itemNameClass);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to " + group_position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (group_position.equals("Computer Accessories Shop")){

                itemListDatabase.insertDataIntoComputerAccessoriesShop(itemNameClass);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to " + group_position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                itemEditorEditText.setText("");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.doneButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(ItemEditorActivity.this, CategoryList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
}
```