# setOnItemLongClickListener for Expanded ListView gives incorrect itemIndex if preceding group is expanded

Tags: android

I'm populating expanded list view by extending BaseExpandableListAdapter.
Code for ChildView:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
convertView=in.inflate(R.layout.details, null);
//set text for various TextViews from ArrayList1 
return convertView;
}
```

Code for GroupView:

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater li= getLayoutInflater();
convertView=li.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
//add data to ArrayList1 and set text for various TextViews
return convertView;
}
```

If a group is expanded and I long press on any of the subsequent group the onItemLongClick method gets (actual index + 1) value for parameter itemIndex. Because of this i get arrayindexoutofbounds exception.

```
elview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int itemIndex, long arg3) {
Log.e("index selected", itemIndex+"");
return false;
}});
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you registering the adapter for a context menu...

Here's the bits from how I've done it without issue:

**adapter creation**

```
    mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, getActivity(),
            R.layout.explistlayout,
            R.layout.explistlayout1,
            new String[] { "_id" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
            new String[] { child },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

**context menu and action**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    if (type == 1) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Event Operations");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit Event");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete Event");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    if (item.getTitle() == "Edit Event") {
        mRowId = info.id;
        EventAddFragment eventadd = new EventAddFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.rightpane, eventadd).commit();
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete Event") {
        mDbHelper.deleteEvent(info.id);
        mGroupsCursor.requery();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

You can also check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353074/android-long-click-on-the-child-views-of-a-expandablelistview) for further details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to add an alert dialog for group/parent and not for it's child items. basically when a user does a 'long press' on any of the item(group/parent) in list view, i want to pop up an alert dialog which needs index/group position.

Comment: problem solved using your idea. thanks a lot. removed type=1 from onCreateContextMenu() so that i get menu for parent too.