# Information about sublistitems ExpandableListView setOnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement the longClickListener to my Expandablelistview. In this listview there are sometimes only **one sublistitem**, sometimes there are **two** of them. So - when this longclick fires the listener, I want to know 1) how many sublistitems are there in this actual groupitem (is there one or two items), 2), if its two sublistitems - which of these two items were longclicked?

I do not know how to use the signature of this method to get the information.

Any ideas?

```
expandableList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



              return false;
          }
      });
```

Comment: This is more complicated than it should be. Read the first couple of answers to this question for more background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353074/android-long-click-on-the-child-views-of-a-expandablelistview

Comment: Thanks! this link really helped me to solve the most important problem - that is to identify the childposition.