# How to get the Object which was clicked in a ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

I wanted to know, how can I get the Object which was clicked in a `ExpandableListView`

I have a `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and here is my method:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Foo children = (Foo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    // view stuff

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // how to get the clicked child object of type Foo?
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // also how to get it here?
            return true;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

How to get the Child element of type `Foo` for the click and long click listener?

Comment: Why aren't you using onItemClickListener? in onClick you could just get your final Foo children

Comment: can't find this method. I only can select the onClick and LongClick via convertView

Comment: Nono you have to apply this metthod on your listView: listview.setOnItemClickListener(...)

Comment: have a look on this tutorial for listviews, it says Everything: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: the problem is, when I click on the child, setOnItemLongClickListener and setOnItemClickListener are not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onChildClick` method in your code.This method is automatically called when you click on child item. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353074/android-long-click-on-the-child-views-of-a-expandablelistview)  link for long press.

```
 public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: and what about the long click?

Comment: I have only used onChildClick() event. Don't know about long click.As mentioned http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html on this link, Expandable listview provides only onChildClick() event.