# Open Popup Dialog from expandableListviewGroup holding

Tags: android, expandablelistview, smartphone

i have a problem and couldn't find any help using Google. I have an extendable listview with some information when clicking on it. Now i want to add something like a popup dialog showing when holding the groupitem.

Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Here is my code i have now:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cocktailView=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.simple_cocktail_list);
    cocktailHash = new HashMap<>();

    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    final StringRequest objectRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            "http://datservice/all/cocktails",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(response);
                    cocktailList = new Gson().fromJson(element.getAsJsonArray(), new TypeToken<List<Cocktail>>() {}.getType());
                    onSuccess(cocktailList);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    String test = error.toString();
                    //Log.e("Rest Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8320128/5465447) shows how you can capture `long click` on **child item**. Based on this answer you can capture `long click` on **group item** as well. Here is an example,

```
cocktailView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
                // Show your pop up dialog
                new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                        .setMessage("Your Message")
                        .show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
});
```